# Laravel HTTP vs HTTPS requests

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, https

My **Laravel** website is deployed on **Heroku**. For example, when I type `http://example.herokuapp.com` -> the UI stays intact. However, when I use `https`, the UI jumbles up and breaks.

How can I fix this?

Comment: did all of your scripts and css files using https?

Comment: clearly you have some http resources, which wont load if the main page is https - suggest you use `//example.com/path/file.ext` in place of `http://example.com/path/file.ext` for any external resources

Comment: how do you are referencing you css and js files

Comment: May be the CSS and JS files are not being loaded on HTTPS, you might be referencing them from HTTP, instead you can use Laravel Helper function to load those or you can simply use `//example.com/<file_path>`

Comment: Have you checked the browser developer tools in search of error messages?

Answer (score 1):

You are having an issue with **mixed content**, you can learn more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content).

**Mixed Content**

> Mixed content occurs when initial HTML is loaded over a secure HTTPS connection, but other resources (such as images, videos, stylesheets, scripts) are loaded over an insecure HTTP connection.

**Solution**

To solve the issue, simply reference all your *scripts*, *stylesheets*, etc. using `//` instead of defining a specific protocol. In this case the resources will always be loaded using the same protocol as the page itself.

- Old: `<img src="http://example.com/picture.jpg">`
- New: `<img src="//example.com/picture.jpg">`

Answer (score 0):

As everyone says, it's because You have some assets loaded under http protocol and your domain is in https.

My recommendation is that You use **asset()**:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/my-image.png') }}">

<link href="{{ asset('css/my-styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{ asset('js/my-script.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: The second argument needs to be `true` in order for it be secure.